# How to always plot up to 100% on bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I have a a snippet of Python code to plot a very basic bar graph which represents a list containing pre-calculated percentages:

```
def plot_errors_percent_bar_graph(list):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    x_labels = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
    ax.bar(x_labels, list, color='green')
    ax.set_ylabel('Percentage of Number of Errors')
    ax.set_xlabel('Labels')
    ax.set_title('Total Percentage Number of Errors')
    plt.show(block=False)
    plt.pause(0.001)
```

The graph only shows the highest percentage from the list on the y-axis (e.g. 80% on the plot shown below):

[image: Example Graph]

How can I always make the graph show from 0% to 100% even if the list doesn't contain a value near that?

Comment: You can use plt.ylim()

Comment: You need to "normalise" the values. The max value goes way beyond 80% in your graph

Comment: `ax.set_ylim(ymax=100)`

Comment: plt.ylim(ymax=100) seems to work perfect! Thank you all for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With matplotlib you can define the limits of values on each axis. To solve your problem, just add the line `ax.set_ylim(ymin=0, ymax=100)` in your function.

[image: Matplotlib image]